# How to find out whether there exist tag or not in the XML?

Tags: java, xml

^_^

I'm using DOM Parser to parse the XML data.

I want to know whether there exist tag or not.

for example ..

```
<a>
  <aa>
  <bb>
</a>
```

In this XML code, If I want to know `<aa>` exist in the XML code, how can I do this?

I've not found out the way yet..T_T

If you know the way .. please let me know..^^;;

Comment: Can you show the code you already have?

Comment: Please find my updated answer..There is a solution for DOM parser too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By XPath:

```
    XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    final Double count=(Double) path.evaluate("count(//bb)", doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
    System.out.println(count.intValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using SAX Parser

```
try {

SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);  // By Default also, it is false
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
reader.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());
reader.parse(new InputSource("./configurationfiles/document.xml"));
} catch (SAXException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**SimpleErrorHandle.java**

```
class SimpleErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

### Using DOM Parser

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(false);  // By Default also, it is false
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        builder.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());

        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource("./configurationfiles/document.xml"));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The element type "bb" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</bb>".
```

Comment: Thank you for answering ..!! ^^ but.. I'm using DOM Parser.. not SAXParser..T_T